# How to make image uploads default to full size?

Tags: images, customization

I want to make it so that when an image is added to a post, full size is selected by default.  It currently defaults to large.

I have tried:

```
function my_set_default_image_size () {
    return 'full';
}
add_filter( 'pre_option_image_default_size', 'my_set_default_image_size' );
```

and

```
add_filter('pre_option_image_default_size', function() { return 'full'; });
```

but neither are working for me.

I'm on WordPress 5.0.3, using the block editor.

Comment: are you using the classic editor or the block editor?

Comment: @TomJNowell the block editor

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like that filter exists in WordPress core. That being said, I have the solution for you. That select uses an option to set the default size:

```
get_option( 'image_default_size', 'medium' );
```

So all you have to do is update that option:

```
update_option( 'image_default_size', 'full' );
```

For reference: [media.php line 1296](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.0.3/src/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L1296)

Answer (score 0):

'pre_option_image_default_size' is ok, but your functions needs to receive a param

```
add_filter('pre_option_image_default_size', function($param) { return 'full'; });
```

See pre_option_{$option} hook.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_option_option/

Comment: Would the definitely make a difference? e.g. you can use the `__return_*`  functions in filters and they don't take arguments.